# $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2=\binom{n+2}{2}+2\binom {n+3}{3}$ counting in two ways

Tags: combinatorics

Consider $S=\{1, 2, 3, 4, ..., n+1\}$ knowing $n\ge 2$ and $T=\{(x,y,z)\in S^3| x<z,y<z\}$ by counting $|T|$ in two ways show that:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2=\binom{n+1}{2}+2\binom {n+1}{3}$$

Comment: $1+4={4\choose2}+2{5\choose3}$?

Comment: I have corrected the problem to what I think you wanted.  Would you please show what you have tried on the problem.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: The answer to the first question below gives you a way to interpret one side of your identity in terms of $|T|$.

- Suppose that $1\le k\le n$. How many members $\langle x,y,z\rangle$ of $T$ have $z=k+1$?

Now $T$ has two kinds of members: those of the form $\langle x,x,z\rangle$ with $x<z$, and those of the form $\langle x,y,z\rangle$ with $x,y<z$ and $x\ne y$.

- How many members of $T$ are of the first kind?
- How many are of the second kind?